# How to use sed to create new txt file without specific words

Tags: bash, shell, sed, cmd, cut

I have a text file that contains $string . How would I use sed to create a new txt file without all occurrences of $string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `sed` command that will replace all the occurrences of your string variable by the the empty string `''`  and by redirecting the output to a new output_file.

```
sed "s/$string//g" input_file > output_file
```

or you can use the following `sed` command:

```
sed -i.bkp "s/$string//g" file
```

to work directly inside the file passed as parameter, `-i.bkp` option will create backup file automatically with an extension `.bkp`, (in the above example `file.bkp`), if no need of backup, use just `-i`

Last but not least, your `$string` variable should not contain any slash `/` if there are any you should escape all of them using `\`. You can create a function to perform this task.